# Consuming JSON object in PHP, sent from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm sending a JSON object to PHP using jQuery via

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: myData,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'html',    
    async: false,
    success: function(html) {
        window.console.log(html);
    }
});
```

and trying to decode the JSON object using

```
$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
```

but the contents of variable are printed as

```
[object Object]
```

with json_decode() returning NULL (of course).

Any ideas what I need to do to get the at the actual JSON data?

Thanks,
Gaz.

Comment: What is the contents of myData?  Can you output (using firebug, e.g.) that to make sure it has the correct contents (and post the results)?

Comment: I've printed it out using window.console.log and it's correct.

Comment: Object
ar: Array
content: "Some more test data"
link_title: ""
title: ""
en: Array
content: "My test data"
link_title: ""
title: ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are sending a string to the PHP.  Jquery by default sends data in a normal post format.  PHP can read this data just fine.  I would recommend just getting the data you need out of the POST array.

If you are trying to serialize a Javascript object via JSON and then convert it back to an object in the PHP side, then you might want to go the JSON route.  You will need a plugin to convert the data from a string to JSON.  You might want to consider:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

You would change the line:

```
   data: myData,
```

To:

```
    data: $.toJSON(myData),
```

Then on the PHP side you will still receive the data in the post array and you can convert it with the following command:

```
$params = json_decode($_POST[]);
```

Comment: OK, it works now. An additional problem was using non-numeric keys in a javascript array. Used $.toJSON and changed to keys to numeric and it works.

By the way, I didn't use $_POST but used contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", and processData: false, then decoded the JSON from   $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"].

Cheers,
Gaz.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do *not* send a JSON object to your php script, just the string 'object Object'.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that! Do you know what I need to change in the jQuery AJAX call to do otherwise?

Thanks,
Gaz.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using $_POST?

I handle all of my JSON requests more or less like this:

```
$params = json_decode($_POST[]);
```

Comment: The result is the same, an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending a string through POST. I recommend using [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to stringify your Javascript object.
Use

var myData = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);

Answer (score -1):

Use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];`

Comment: The two are equivalent anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You've set your dataType to 'html' in your ajax call. Shouldn't it be 'json'? I think your nice json object is being condensed down into a meaningless string.

Comment: dataType -> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.